# Replace multiple words in one line from a .txt file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to replace multiple words in a txt file.

An example with two lines would be

```
phone number: 123 addr: xyz
phone no: 456 home address: abc
```

Lets say that I'd like to replace "phone number" and "phone no" with *phonenum* and "addr" & "address" with *address1*.

Currently I only know how to do it with running multiple sed commands and I'm looking for some guidance to find a more efficient way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Perl, with the hash whose keys are the words to be replaced, and values - their desired replacements. The string of keys joined on a pipe serves as the pattern in substitution operator `s///g`, with the `/g` modifier to enable multiple substitutions per line.

```
echo "phone number: 123 addr: xyz\nphone no: 456 home address: abc" > in.txt

perl -lpe '
BEGIN {
    %re = (
        q{phone number}  => q{phonenum},
        q{phone no}      => q{phonenum},
        q{addr}          => q{address1},
        q{address}       => q{address1},
    );
    $re_str = join q{|}, keys %re; # "phone number|phone no|addr|address"
}
s/\b($re_str)\b/$re{$1}/g;
' in.txt > out.txt
```

Output in file `out.txt`:

```
phonenum: 123 address1: xyz
phonenum: 456 home address1: abc
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`q{...}` : an alternative method to specify single-quoted strings (`'...'` are not used here because they have to be escaped within single-quoted Perl one-liner).

`s/\b($re_str)\b/$re{$1}/g;` : Parenthesis around `$re_str` capture the pattern into `$1` variable. `\b` means word break, that is, either the start or the end of a word. Adding `\b` is needed to prevent replacing, for example, `home address` with `home address1ess`, depending on the order of evaluation.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: It may convert `home address` into `home address1ess` depending on the order of evaluation.

Comment: @tshiono Thank you for pointing out the bug in the regex that caused, for example, replacing `home address` with `home address1ess`, depending on the order of evaluation. Fixed by adding `\b`.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Now it works fine! I've ++ed for your nice answer.